# Remove consecutive duplicate rows in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table having 3 columns (id, amount, time). The table is arranged in ascending order based on id. I want to remove all consecutive rows that have same value in the amount column except the first one.

eg:

```
id: 12,15,16,17,19,22
amount: 555,546,546,53,53,500
time:
```

Answer:

```
id:12,15,17,22    amount: 555,546,53,500    time:
```

The time column is same for consecutive rows whenever the consecutive rows have same values in the amount column.
I searched on SO but could not find a similar question

Comment: Refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439054/postgresql-with-delete-relation-does-not-exists , answer available in SO.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to delete duplicate entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746213/how-to-delete-duplicate-entries).  Also, there's no such thing as "consecutive rows" in SQL, not like you're thinking.  You can explicitly ask the database to `ORDER BY <column>` rows, but if you leave that clause out, the order you see is undefined.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(amount) over (order by id) as prev_amount
      from t
     ) t
where prev_amount is distinct from amount;
```

Comment: Sorry I posted while still typing the question

Answer (score 1):

This might not be an effective method but it works faster if you have large table (>2 million rows).

1. `Copy` the table as csv format with `DISTINCT` on amount column:

   `\COPY (SELECT DISTINCT ON (amount) * FROM Tablename) to '/home/user/table.csv' with csv delimiter ',';`
2. `Truncate` the previous table :

   `TRUNCATE TABLE Tablename;`
3. Copy back the dumped table :

   `\COPY Tablename from '/home/user/table.csv' with csv delimiter ',';`

I've tried deleting duplicates but it took me a day for the query to complete. This method serves me well.