# PostgreSQL array - Remove consecutive identical values

Tags: arrays, postgresql

In a `PostgreSQL` text `array` I want to remove consecutive identical values. A `distinct` isn't enough because I can have duplicate values but not consecutive, and I want to keep them. The order of values have importance.

For example

```
SELECT ARRAY['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A'];
```

Should return `{A,B,C,D,A}`

-- Edit

AS @MkSpring Mk said, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49077368/remove-consecutive-duplicate-rows-in-postgresql) suggest an answer. I try to adapt it:

```
WITH q_array AS (
    SELECT ARRAY['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A'] AS full_array
    ), q_unnest AS (
        SELECT  
        unnest(full_array) AS unnest_array
        FROM q_array
        ), q_id AS (
            SELECT
            row_number() OVER () AS id,
            unnest_array
            FROM q_unnest
        )
SELECT
array_agg(q_id.unnest_array) AS array_logical
FROM (SELECT q_id.*, lag(q_id.unnest_array) OVER (ORDER BY q_id.id) AS unnest_array_logical FROM q_id) q_id
WHERE unnest_array_logical IS DISTINCT FROM q_id.unnest_array
```

I find this syntax very verbose, maybe my approach is not efficient enough.

Is this syntax ok ? Is it a best practice to create a function or can I write it directly in a query ?

Comment: Partly because in my configuration I don't have a native ID column. And I'm also asking if it's good practice to write it in the query or in a dedicated function.

Answer (score 0):

To improve query performance, I made this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_remove_consecutive_duplicates(
    array_vals anyarray)
    RETURNS TABLE(array_logical anyarray) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
      RETURN QUERY 
      WITH q_array AS (
    SELECT array_vals AS full_array
    ), q_unnest AS (
        SELECT  
        unnest(full_array) AS unnest_array
        FROM q_array
        ), q_id AS (
            SELECT
            row_number() OVER () AS id,
            unnest_array
            FROM q_unnest
        )
SELECT
array_agg(q_id.unnest_array) AS array_logical
FROM (SELECT q_id.*, lag(q_id.unnest_array) OVER (ORDER BY q_id.id) AS unnest_array_logical FROM q_id) q_id
WHERE unnest_array_logical IS DISTINCT FROM q_id.unnest_array;
    END;
  
$BODY$;
```

My query will now write like this:

```
SELECT array_remove_consecutive_duplicates(ARRAY['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A']);
```

It's a bit faster and easier to use in a query than my fist approach. Maybe it's not the good way or my syntax isn't efficient. If someone have a better way to suggest, I'll take it.