# Removing Duplicate Rows in PostgreSQL with multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table "votes" with the following columns: 
`voter`, `election_year`, `election_type`, `party`
I need to remove all duplicate rows of the combination of `voter` and `election_year`, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this.

I ran the following:

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT voter, 
       election_year,
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY voter, election_year ORDER BY voter) as RN

FROM votes
)
DELETE
FROM CTE where RN>1
```

based on another StackOverflow answer, but it seems this is specific to SQL Server.  I've seen ways to do this using unique ID's, but this particular table doesn't have that luxury.  How can I adopt the above script to remove the duplicates I need?  Thanks!

EDIT: Per request, creation of the table with some example data:

```
CREATE TABLE public.votes
(
    voter varchar(10),
    election_year smallint,
    election_type varchar(2),
    party varchar(3)
);

INSERT INTO votes
    (voter, election_year, election_type, party)
VALUES
    ('2435871347', 2018, 'PO', 'EV'),
    ('2435871347', 2018, 'RU', 'EV'),
    ('2435871347', 2018, 'GE', 'EV'),
    ('2435871347', 2016, 'PO', 'EV'),
    ('2435871347', 2016, 'GE', 'EV'),
    ('10215121/8', 2016, 'GE', 'ED')
;
```

Comment: "based on another StackOverflow answer, but it seems this is specific to SQL Server." This query looks perfect PostgreSQL syntax to me.  PostgreSQL also support `WITH .. AS` (common table expressions) and  `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (....)` just fine.. "How can I adopt the above script to remove the duplicates I need? Thanks!"  Very hard to say without table structure and example data.   Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "**Help others reproduce the problem**"

Comment: I apologize, the error given is "[42P01] ERROR: relation "cte" does not exist Position: 157"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Delete from or updating CTEs doesn't work in Postgres, see the accepted answer of ["PostgreSQL with-delete “relation does not exists”"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439054/postgresql-with-delete-relation-does-not-exists).

Since you have no primary key you may (ab)use the [`ctid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-system-columns.html) pseudo column to identify the rows to delete.

```
WITH
cte
AS
(
SELECT ctid,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY voter,
                                       election_year
                          ORDER BY voter) rn
       FROM votes
)
DELETE FROM votes
       USING cte
       WHERE cte.rn > 1
             AND cte.ctid = votes.ctid;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=b4d70a39b343d41627863b80b2c2d21b)

And probably think about introducing a primary key.

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting [42703] ERROR: column cte.ctid does not exist

Comment: @JGrindal: Sure you copied the statement completely? Or have you just edited yours? If, have you also added the `ctid` to the `SELECT` in the CTE?

Comment: Yup, forgot ctid in my CTE.  Thanks!

Comment: plus for dbfiddle :D

Answer (score 25):

Here's an option

```
DELETE FROM votes T1
    USING   votes T2
WHERE   T1.ctid < T2.ctid 
    AND T1.voter = T2.voter 
    AND T1.election_year  = T2.election_year;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4d45d/5

Answer (score 2):

The ctid field is a field that exists in every PostgreSQL table and is unique for each record in a table and denotes the location of the tuple.
You did almost right just need ctid as you  have no unique id for each row

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT ctid,voter, 
       election_year,
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY voter, election_year ORDER BY voter) as RN

FROM votes
)
delete  FROM votes v where v.ctid in (select CTE.ctid from  CTE where CTE.RN>1)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4d45d/14